# Open a jsp page when path is dynamic

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I have a jsp page(with corresponding servlet) that needs to be open whatever the path is specified. For example my jsp is  webapps/test/index.jsp
It should be opened as http://localhost/[path] where the path is an arbitrary string.

e.g.localhost/xxxx and localhost/yyyy shall open the same webapps/test/index.jsp.

I am using Tomcat 7.0 and Servlet 3.0.

Can this be implemented by tomcat or servlet configuration? What are the options to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map `/*` to that JSP page by registering a new servlet in your `web.xml`:

```
(...)

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>index-view</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/test/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>index-view</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

(...)
```

More info on Oracle's pages: [(LINK)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configurejsp.html#wp157809)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a servletfilter and in that filter use the requestDispatcher.forward method to forward requests to the target page. You can get the url of the request using

```
String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();
```

and forward that request using

```
request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(newUrl)
                    .forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your project's config files,ensure the servlet-mapping is right and unique in the web.xml .